# Why does changing this picture in any way ruins the way it displays in unity?

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, png

I downloaded a picture from a tutorial on how to create Flappy Bird in Unity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihvBiJ1oC9U

When I use it in Unity it works perfect however when I try to make any changes to it, whether by simple "Paint" or "Photoshop", the picture turns blurry and I can't understand why, here is a video where you can see the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mke4V.jpg

Here are 2 of the picture's details page, on the left, the one I downloaded from the tutorial that works good, on the right the one I simply changed some pixels in "Paint": https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsLnF.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you apply the **right settings** for your new image. Specifically the **Alpha** and **Filter Mode**.

[image: Image import settings]